# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/a8479867/public_html/index.php on line 538

Tags: php, variables, syntax-error

So i'll use php for about 3-4 week now and now i'll run intro a error this one

if you need more information just ask's :D THANKS!

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE**

here my php code the error is on line '538'

```
<?php
$p=strtolower$_GET['p'];
if (isset($p) && preg_match("/^[a-z0-9]+$/i",$p){
if(file_exists)("pages/$p.html")){
include "pages/$p.html";
}
else{ 
include "page/404.html"
}
}
else {
include "page/404.html";
}
?>
```

Comment: Line 538 ? We can see just a few lines of code here.

Comment: You forgot semi-colon in your first else statement.

Comment: Please consult the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/) for the correct syntax usage and functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$p=strtolower($_GET['p']);
if(file_exists("page/".$p.".html")){
include "page/".$p.".html";
}else{ 
include "page/404.html";
}
?>
```

Comment: Still have errors in your code

Comment: try again i update code

Comment: i first thank for the fast reply i fix everything you've said but i still got the same error any other idea ?

Comment: try now, i tested its work

Comment: work now with update ?

Comment: yes thank ! :D i've got another problem but for a different thing i'll post here or create another topic ?

Comment: create another but with normail subject

Comment: normal object what do you mean ? sorry i'm french canadien so sometime i don't really understand english ahah

Comment: normaly subject - without error on subject, like (have error on or in ...) its ok, i'm russian :-)

Answer (score 1):

Missing semi colon:

`include "page/404.html"`

Should be

`include "page/404.html";`

Also the If statement is not well formed

`if(file_exists)("pages/$p.html")){`

Should be

`if(file_exists("pages/$p.html")){`

And you are missing brackets around your `strtolower()` function call

`$p=strtolower$_GET['p'];`

Should be

`$p=strtolower($_GET['p']);`

Comment: `if (isset($p) && preg_match("/^[a-z0-9]+$/i",$p){` also have error.. as closing bracket is not there..

Answer (score -2):

You are missing a semi colon after 404.html.
Also

```
if(file_exists)("pages/$p.html")){
```

Should be

```
if( file_exists("pages/$p.html") ){
```

I'd generally advise against coding in that sort of style as it's easy to make a mistake and introduce a local file inclusion exploit.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_inclusion_vulnerability#Local_File_Inclusion

It is better to have a white list of pages and match against that if you do want code to work in that way.

Comment: One more error to find :P